# Jquery - How to select the nearest Dom element to the TD

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I need to use a selector to get the HTML content of a poor CSS formated webpage.

How can I get the content of the text with "**I need this here**" ?

```
<tbody>
    <tr class="nth">
        <td class="title">Address</td>
        <td>I need this here</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Can someone give some clues?

Using this I got "Address":

```
$('tbody tr.nth td').html()
```

Answer (score 1):

This should help to find the second `<td>` child.

```
$('tbody tr.nth td:eq(1)').html()
```

Reference: 
[:eq() Selector](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)

Comment: instead of such a specific selector, you can even use `$('.nth td:eq(1)').html()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)

> Reduce the set of matched elements to the one at the specified index.

```
$('tbody tr.nth td').eq(1).html()
```

OR

```
$('tbody tr.nth td.title').next('td').html()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`:last`](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/) selector to select the *last* matched TD:

```js
document.write($('tbody tr.nth td:last').html())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr class="nth">
        <td class="title">Address</td>
        <td>I need this here</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<hr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$(".nth :not(.title)").html();
```

```js
console.log($(".nth :not(.title)").html())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr class="nth">
        <td class="title">Address</td>
        <td>I need this here</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
  </table>
```